# Filling a strange webform in python

Tags: python, html

I am trying build a simple program that fills a webform and then extracts the a data from the resulted website, it should be pretty straight-forward and after a short web research (mostly from this website) I came to the conclusion that  python would be my best choice.(with urllib)

I would give a specific example of what I am trying to do and hopefully it will clarify things:

1. Lets say I want an automatic script that gets the price for hotel, the website would be:
   the Hilton website
2. In that webpage I want to fill the query as follows: the "where are you going" should have N.Y.C and departure and arrival date.
3. If used from the browser, I will get a the next page with the results for the query I just filled and from that webpage I want to scrape the prices.

Lets assume that scraping the data can be done from the html source code.

Well, that's how I thought to do it (very general description....)

```
import urllib
import urllib.request

url = 'http://www3.hilton.com/en/index.html'
query_args = { 'searchQuery':' New York, NY ', 'arrivalDate':'31 Oct 2013' ,                         'departureDate': '04 Nov 2013' }
print (query_args)
data = urllib.parse.urlencode(query_args)
print (data)
request = urllib.request.Request(url);
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request,data)
html = response.read()
print (html)
```

1. First of all I get an the following error when I am sending the request:" TypeError: POST data should be bytes or an iterable of bytes. It cannot be of type str." anyone knows why?
2. If I got it right I would assume that I would accept the response for the following website. hilton_website with the urlencode segment in the end (searchQuery=+New+York%2C+NY&arrivalDate=31+Oct+2013&departureDate=04+Nov+2013)

But there is no such website (  when I am typing the full  address to the browser url)
it looks like all the results (and it doesn't matter what was your query or how you filled the form ) appear on the same webpage: hilton_web_site...en_US/hi/search/findhotels/results.htm?view=LIST

So what am I doing wrong? I thought that the way to fill a web form.

Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: Rule #1: Send **all** the form data in your request (even if empty), otherwise the server will hate on you. Rule #2: Are you sure the data is formatted correectly? (The TEXT presented in say a drop-down is not nescessarly the **VALUE** that is being sent to the server. If you're using Google Chrome, Menu -> Tools -> Developer Tools -> (tab) Network -> **press** the hilton page file that you send your search to.. Now, this should show you "Request Headers" and to the right a small text that says "Show Source", press that and view what you're actually sending to the server.)

Comment: can you explain how is it possible that 2 different quaireis has the same request?

Comment: Short answer: They don't. They can't have the same identical data in their queries. the `POST /page HTTP1.1` is the same, but the data can not be.

Comment: Just a recommendation, you can use [Mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize) to browse a site and select/fill/submit forms. It is a headless browser implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a dump of hiltons search form (which, i instructed you how to get but can not paste it all in the comment section so here you go), i forgot to mention that you should check the "Form data" raw data in Chrome tho which was my bad.. anyway..

RAW data (so you can understand how a POST request works)

### Request Header

```
POST /en_US/hi/search/findhotels/index.htm?WT.bid=Home,,,find_button HTTP/1.1
Host: www3.hilton.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 475
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Origin: http://www3.hilton.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Referer: http://www3.hilton.com/en/index.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: mmcore.tst=0.626; ClrCSTO=T; ClrSSID=1382526492268-11812; ClrOSSID=1382526492268-11812; ClrSCD=1382526492268; mmid=-1914085652%7CAQAAAAq0Q+DZtwkAAA%3D%3D; mmcore.pd=-1914085652%7CAQAAAAq0Q+DZtwkAAA%3D%3D; mmcore.srv=ldnvwcgus01; K3R7=3U24QMiCUbjeh65LoEI31TTjisY8czr4zkIUe06gsA4A5lc0bIKrEhQ; GWSESSIONID=qYDpSnSLNFnJ5CrJrwlSWW7CNBHL7vXSMndGmnxghGns1rLjt2lX!-1490734837; __atuvc=1%7C43; mm_pc_HHonorsPoints=false; mm_pers_storage=loggedin%3Ano%7CStayDuration%3A1-2%20nights%7CDaysToBooking%3A0-1%7CSatStay%3Ano%7CChildren%3Ano%7CBrand%3Ahi%7CHHonorsPoints%3Afalse%7CFlexDates%3Afalse%7CPromoCode%3Ano%7Cproperties8%3Ano%7Chotelcode%3Ano; WT_FPC=id=6f7c5181-8354-430b-b943-9bb95bf2c75c:lv=1382490515002:ss=1382490495203
```

### Form data

```
searchQuery=N.Y.C&arrivalDate=23+Oct+2013&departureDate=24+Oct+2013&_flexibleDates=on&numberOfRooms=1&numberOfAdults%5B0%5D=1&numberOfChildren%5B0%5D=0&numberOfAdults%5B1%5D=1&numberOfChildren%5B1%5D=0&numberOfAdults%5B2%5D=1&numberOfChildren%5B2%5D=0&numberOfAdults%5B3%5D=1&numberOfChildren%5B3%5D=0&promoCode=&groupCode=&corporateId=&_travelAgentRate=on&_aaaRate=on&_aarpRate=on&_seniorRate=on&_governmentRate=on&offerId=&bookButton=false&searchType=ALL&roomKeyEnable=true
```

And these are they keys (not values) that you **need** to send with each search query:

- searchQuery
- arrivalDate
- departureDate
- _flexibleDates
- numberOfRooms
- numberOfAdults%5B0%5D
- numberOfChildren%5B0%5D
- numberOfAdults%5B1%5D
- numberOfChildren%5B1%5D
- numberOfAdults%5B2%5D
- numberOfChildren%5B2%5D
- numberOfAdults%5B3%5D
- numberOfChildren%5B3%5D
- promoCode
- groupCode
- corporateId
- _travelAgentRate
- _aaaRate
- _aarpRate
- _seniorRate
- _governmentRate
- offerId
- bookButton
- searchType
- roomKeyEnable

And this is what a python build of the whole thing would look like:

```
from socket import *
s = socket()

POST = 'searchQuery=N.Y.C&arrivalDate=23+Oct+2013&departureDate=......'

header = ''
header += 'POST /en_US/hi/search/findhotels/index.htm?WT.bid=Home,,,find_button HTTP/1.1\r\n'
header += 'Host: www3.hilton.com\r\n'
header += 'Connection: keep-alive\r\n'
header += 'Content-Length: ' + str(len(POST)) + '\r\n'
header += 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8\r\n'
header += 'Origin: http://www3.hilton.com\r\n'
header += 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) \r\n'
header += 'Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36\r\n'
header += 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n'
header += 'Referer: http://www3.hilton.com/en/index.html\r\n'
header += 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch\r\n'
header += 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8\r\n'
header += '\r\n'

s.connect(('www3.hilton.com', 80))
s.send(header+POST)
print(s.recv(8192))
```

And that would give you what you're looking for.
Note that i left out the cookie field in the header.. normally the server doesn't care to much about it because it's an ancient technique and there for the server usually assumes that if no cookies was given, just give the client new ones and assume it's the first visit even tho (well technically it is but) it is'nt really the actual first page.

### Also note:

All data in the `POST` variable must be URL encoded as such: `urlencode(key)=urlencode(val)&` for each pair. Note how i did not url-encode the `=` or the `&` in this raw POST data.

This is where you wouldn't need to worry about it because urllib does it for you. But this gives you a understanding of how HTTP requests work.

Comment: so the fuction i was using "urlopen" in the script above (with the full queary parametrs) is not enough? can it be done with that function only?

Comment: @user2910088 It can be done with `urlopen`, you just need to add more parameters to your POST data (more specifically, all the items in my list above even if the values are empty)

Comment: Hi, It looks like i manage after adding the full form fileds and casting the 'data' into bytes i am getting some kind of a response i print the output of html = response.read()
print (html)

Comment: Hi, It looks like i manage after adding the full form fileds and casting the 'data' into bytes i am getting some kind of a response i print the output of html = response.read()
print (html) . is what i am seeing printed is the html code just as if i would press on "show source code" in the browser? it doesn't look the same though i am looking for the prices and they cant be found in that output.