# Getting ALL the data from a webpage with python

Tags: python, html, webforms

this is a followup question to something i  asked before (take a  look at [Filling a strange webform in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19535970/filling-a-strange-webform-in-python))

I am filling a webform using python and sending the encoded request with urlrequest, then i am printing the response received and i see that i don't  get all the information (compared to what i would get if i will look at "show source code" in the browser).After investigating i understand that the response only include the static html part of the webpage and not the all the content.

so basically the question is how do i get the specific part of the information i am looking for , the concrete example, lets say i am filling a webform in the hilton website, the response i get doesn't include the price, 
**can you tell me how do i get the "price" from such a website?**

thats the basic code i am using:

```
url = 'http://www3.hilton.com/en/index.html'
query_args = { 'searchQuery':' New York, NY', 'arrivalDate':'31 Oct 2013'....}
data = urllib.parse.urlencode(query_args)
request = urllib.request.Request(url);
binary_data = data.encode(encoding= 'utf-8')
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request,binary_data)
html = response.read() 
print (html)
```

Thanks.

Comment: The response you get **should** always be the same with the response you see from the browser, unless your request is different. Try copy-pasting and comparing it with the response you have.

Comment: If the piece of information you are trying to extract is inserted into the page with javascript - you'll have to use something able to execute javascript, e.g. selenium.

Comment: You can use for example Firebug (in Firefox) to see how page is "talking" with server. Maybe page use javascript (and AJAX) to get more info. Or page send some cookie, session number, different user-agent and server send more info.